# How to dismiss a Page component opened in a Modal from within the page itself? - Ionic4

Tags: ionic-framework

With Ionic 4 the `ViewController` does not have a `dismiss()` function anymore. How to dismiss the page presented through a modal?

Currently, I am passing a reference of the `Modal` to the page, then in the page, I call `this.modal.dismiss()`. I don't think this is the best way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the modalcontroller dismiss method like so:

```
public modalController: ModalController
```

Call

```
this.modalController.dismiss();
```

Thats all